# Android Studio Font Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, fonts

I downloaded a .ttf file for the font and saved it in font Resource folder of my application. Now I see garbage fonts and symbols rather than text in my android studio layout preview. Here is the screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cg4.png). While I run the app, everything works fine and the output texts are in english language as I desired. But the problem seems to be in android studio layout preview. I tired rebuilding and cleaning my project but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you put the ttf file inside asset folder in the resource folder? Did you define the typeface inside your activity or fragment?

Comment: app/src/main/res/font here is path for the font folder. I have defined font in xml as android:fontFamily="@font/ " rather than using typeface. I have also used type at one place in this app inside recycler view adapter.

Comment: @ R.Maharjan , you may want to follow how it is done here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to File from menu and click Invalidate Caches / Restart .

File>Invalidate Caches / Restart and select invalidate and restart

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading alternative .ttf file and include in your project. Follow the instructions in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml developer link working perfectly.